# tvOS how to check if the UITabBar is focused

Tags: ios, swift, focus, tvos, focus-engine

I'm looking for a way to make a custom transition when changing the focus from or to the UITabBar.

I'm currently trying this by overriding the `didUpdateFocus` method but I seem to be unable to check if the the tabBar is focused.

The tabBar itself seem to never be in the "focused" state:

```swift
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinatora)
{
    super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)

    print(self.tabBar.isFocused) // always false
}
```

When checking the `UIFocusUpdateContext` the currently focused element is a `UITabBarButton`.

But I'm unable to check if the context is an instance of `UITabBarButton` because that type isn't available:

```swift
context.nextFocusedItem is UITabBarButton // can't compile
```

I'm really stuck here and would love any suggestions on how to tackle this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This answer probably won't help the OP (it was asked more than a year ago), but as I was struggling with the same issue, a presentation from [WWDC17](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/224/) helped me figure it out:

`UIView`, `UIViewController`, `UIWindow`, etc. all conform to the `UIFocusEnvironment` protocol. The tabBar itself never actually receives direct focus, so the correct way to check if one of its buttons has focus is by checking if its environment contains the UIFocusItem:

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let nextFocusedItem = context.nextFocusedItem,
        self.tabBar.contains(nextFocusedItem) {
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

I'm sure the asker figured this out ages ago, but I thought I'd throw this answer up for anyone else that happens to have the same question later.

Answer (score 0):

First add extension for `UIView` if it has superview:

```
public func hasSuperView(_ view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if self == view {
        return true
    }
    if let superview = superview {
        return superview.hasSuperView(view)
    }
    return false
}
```

Then add extension for `UIFocusUpdateContext` to check if view has focus:

```
public func viewHasFocus(_ view: UIView) -> Bool {
    guard let nextFocusedView = nextFocusedView else { return false }
    return nextFocusedView.hasSuperView(view) || view.hasSuperView(nextFocusedView)
}
```

Then use context in this method to check if tabbar has focus:

```
   override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if context.viewHasFocus(tabBar) {}
}
```

Also please override this method in your UITabBarController subclass

Answer (score -1):

I have created extension on UIView which will check if there is focus somewhere in its hierarchy:

```
func containsFocus() -> Bool {
    if self.isFocused { return true }
    else {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview.containsFocus() { return true }
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

This way you can check if your UITabBar has focus.

**Note:**

This is very expensive way of checking if your view has focus, because it is recursive function and it will potentially traverse the whole hierarchy of your view.

**Tip:**

If you are trying to implement custom transition when selecting tabs in UITabBar you should use UITabBarDelegate method:

```
 func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)
```

If not, just ignore this tip.